# Different memory usage on different server with the same PHP website

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I have a PHP website build with Zend Framework 1.11. And I got different memory usage on the following two servers:

A:
MacOS + Apache/2.2.20 + PHP 5.3.6

B:
Scientific Linux 64 + Apache/2.2.15 + PHP 5.3.3

For a exactly same page and condition, it cost 14MB on server A, but only 4MB on server B (calculate by xdebug).

here is the mainly difference step:

```
A:
11288560 Zend_Application->run( )
B:
2740744 Zend_Application->run( )
```

Can anyone tell me what's the problem? 
And is there any way I can analyse the memory's detail usage?

Comment: not surprised at all, Linux has much better memory management. and you have made no mention of hardware differences. also the default settings on php and Apache for those two servers are different - really why did you expect the same results?

Comment: because of the memory cost difference is too big...I just want to know what may cause it. Sever A is run on a MBAir, and Server B is in a Vmware on the same machine. @Dagon

Comment: huge OS difference. end of story. no one hosts on macOS

Comment: I analyzed xdebug's trace files, and found out that in A server require_once & include_once cost 10 times memory more than server B. Of course I won't use OS for host. Just wondering whether there are something wrong with my code. Thanks for your advise :D

Comment: Maybe 32bit versus 64bit? One server is 32bit and the other 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for this are:

Different PHP versions *can* use more or less memory, although in this case it's unlikely given the subtle difference between the two versions.

More likely, it's that the system with higher usage has more mods enabled in the php config.