# PHP Not releasing memory

Tags: php, memory

Got a problem with a php script on my production environment.

The aim of my script is to read a XML File, parse it and generate new XML records to insert in SOLR.
The XML contains many Documents and I loop on the Documents.

Since the last release the script crashed because of memory errors.
I log the memory used at the beginning of the loop with get_memory_usage() and I see that it grows regulary.

I don't use static variables, all variables are reassign in the loop. As I read that concatenation might cause memory problem, I use an array and implode after the loop.

Actually my main problem is that the used memory keep stable on my test environment and on the dev one. The scripts are exactly the sames, configuration is the same to (deployed with puppet). Only the hardware is differend (VM on differents clouds).
Of course the input files are the sames to.

Do you have any idea of what can cause this difference between my environments?
All suggestions that can help accepted, really stucked on this

Comment: Without knowin much about PHP and its memory handling, if you can check the memory usage at any time you could try running it after each line of code for example and see which part of your code actually generates garbage compared to your test/dev enviroment and maybe get some clues. Other than that it's probably going to be hard to say whats wrong without knowing what hardware it works on and what hardware it doesnt.

Comment: Actually there isn't a function which comsum all the memory, it really seems that the memory is never released. Would you know which system parameters could affected this behavior?

Comment: I did a quick google and came up with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223205/different-memory-usage-on-different-server-with-the-same-php-website

If you know what hardware the server is running that eats up your memory maybe include that in a search and see if anyone else had similar problems.

Comment: I saw this, but I run my scripts on two Linux VM deployed with puppet. Only the physical hardware is different. And the behavior is radicaly different between my two envs, one release the memory iterating the loop, the other one never.